# meaning of memory size in tensorflow

Tags: memory, tensorflow, gpu

I wonder what are the units of the memory indicated by these instructions when using tensorflow

[image]

I know I have 32 GB RAM and 6GB GPU but can't figure out units of this output. Your advice is appreciated. Thanks.